# How to set default on insert or create or save in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In mongoose I use insert or save to create new document in my userRole collection but they doesn't set default value defined in mongoose schemma.

```
let userRole = new Schema({
    roleName: { type: String },
    isActive: { type: String, enum: ["YES", "NO"], defalut: "YES" }
});
```

Mongoose provide setDefaultOnInsert option but it work only with findOneAndUpdate. So How can I set default value using save or insert while creating a new document?

```
createRole: (callback) => {
            let dataToSave = {roleName: "ADMIN"}
            return DBFunction.saveData(Models.userRole, dataToSave, (err, data) => {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                if (!data || !data._id) return callback("Something went worng!");
                logger.debug("\nUserRole Created --->>>\n", data)
                return callback(null, data);
            });
        }
```

Database Functions file or DBFunction

```
exports.saveData = (model, data, callback) => new model(data).save((err, result) => err ? callback(err) : callback(null, result));

exports.insert = (model, data, options, callback) => model.collection.insert(data, options, (err, result) => err ? callback(err) : callback(null, result));
```

In mongodb, the document created is

```
{
    roleName: "ADMIN"
}
```

I want like this:

```
{
    roleName: "ADMIN",
    isActive: "YES"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `default` option. There's a typo in your config. You are using `defalut`.